# Nuget package manager console

Tags: powershell, nuget

can I get the name of the active configuration in a powershell variable inside nuget powershell console ? I know there is a $DTE, but I don't know how to get to the active configuration name ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the active configuration like so:

```
$dte.solution.solutionbuild.activeconfiguration
```